# How to use TouchableNativeFeedback in React native android?

Tags: react-native

I am getting warnings while using this component. Trying to use this component as a button. I tried require('TouchableNativeFeedback') but no use. I also tried to npm install TouchableNativeFeedback, but failed. How should it be incorporated in my react native android code?

```
 {
    var TouchableNativeFeedback= require('TouchableNativeFeedback');
    var Button= require('react-native-button');
    var {

      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      Image,
      TouchableNativeFeedback,

    } = React;

    var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
      render: function() {

        return (

          <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              My first App
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
               we should get started
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                Nice!!
            </Text>
          <Image source={require('./abc.png')} style={styles.img} >
          <Text style={styles.welcome}> Inside an image! </Text>
          </Image>
          <TouchableNativeFeedback
            style={styles.img} >
              <View>
              <Text style= {styles.instructions}> 
              Button! 
              </Text>
              </View>
          </ TouchableNativeFeedback>     
          <Button style={styles.img} onClick="this.butclick">
          <View>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          This is a Button 
          </Text>
          </View>
          </Button>


          </View>

        );
      }
    });

}
```

Comment: Try using Buttons from NativBase

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be implement like this, see the [react-native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html#content) for more functionality.

```
​ <TouchableNativeFeedback
     background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('red')}>
     <View style={styles.view}>
        <Text style={style.text}>Text Here</Text>
     </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

Answer (score 3):

best practice to use TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple is to check the api version of devices first, because this background type is available on Android API level 21+.

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

<TouchableNativeFeedback
  onPress={this.follow}
  background={
    Platform.Version >= 21 ?
      TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('rgba(0,0,0,.2)', true) :
      TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()
  }
>
```

Comment: Doesn't it fallback to `SelectableBackground` by default?

Answer (score 0):

`require` isn't necessary.
TouchableNativeFeedback is like Text, Image or View.

```
var Button= require('react-native-button');
var {

  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,

} = React;

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

return (

  <View style={styles.container}>

  <TouchableNativeFeedback
    style={styles.img} >
      <View>
      <Text style= {styles.instructions}> 
      Button! 
      </Text>
      </View>
  </ TouchableNativeFeedback>     
  </View>

);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to import the respective dependency(TouchableNativeFeedback):

```
import { TouchableNativeFeedback, View, Text } from 'react-native';
```

After this, you can use it as:

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this._onPressButton()} key={index}>
     <View>
         <Text>Click Me</Text>
     </View>
 </TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

**Note**: Make sure to add the respective click function(this._onPressButton()) in your code, otherwise you will get an error.